# Is there a way of using Jira with XRAY to trigger an external build?

Tags: jira, jira-xray

I'm new to stack overflow so I hope I'm not asking the same question as another user or structuring my question in a way which is difficult to read.

**Background to my problem**

I'm trying to build an automation framework for testing the functionality of a website, In order to be consider a success it will need to:

1. Trigger the build of a single/ set of tests written in cucumber - these are supported by a feature context written in PHP (laravel dusk).
2. Execute said single/ set of tests and produce a JSON file containing execution results i.e. Pass|Fail - completed
3. Curl the JSON file, produced by the build, to JIRA - imported as test execution results - completed

So an overall description of how I want the process to unfold is as follows:

1. User's will be able to either create or select a test and add that to a
   test execution in JIRA.
2. Be able to easily meet a condition which will act as a trigger.
3. Have an external program such as Gitlab or Jenkins build the project and generate a JSON file.
4. Have the generated JSON file be imported to JIRA via a curl command.
5. If successful in all steps, then the test results should be visible on JIRA.

**Question**

The trouble I'm having is that I can't find any examples of a system using JIRA to trigger an external build - I've seen people use JIRA to record changes/ commits/ merge request etc on Git, but never hosting tests on JIRA and triggering an external program to run said test.

If I have missed an example of people doing this via a native feature, a plugin or any other way then I would be grateful for a link on how they achieved this, if none are found then any advise on how to proceed would also be greatly appreciated as all other success requirements have a working proof of concept except this which is the most crucial part - if people can't initiate a build in a manner which is easy to do so, then people will be reluctant to use it or help another user when they are stuck.

I'm hoping it'll be as easy as clicking execute on a test execution but am open to all theories.

Answer (score 1):

Triggering builds or test automation is something that neither Jira nor Xray provide out-of-the-box.
However, there are some ways of achieving it.

- Using Automation for Jira (which is now an Atlassian product), as [detailed in this tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Automation+for+Jira#IntegrationwithAutomationforJira-UsageExamples)
- Using ScriptRunner app, as [detailed in this tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+ScriptRunner#IntegrationwithScriptRunner-TriggeraJenkinsprojectbuildfromaTestPlan)

There's an [extensive KB article from Xray](https://docs.getxray.app/display/ProductKB/%5BXray+Server%5D+Triggering+automation+from+Xray) detailing some possible solutions.

Note that triggering automation may be more or less complex, depending exactly on your needs. If you just want to trigger a build in a CI tool, where you have there the logic for deciding which tests to run, this is simple. If in the other hand, you wish to "trigger the selected list of tests" in some CI tool, this will require additional effort from your side, as you need to implement some custom logic in the CI tool to handle this.